# Selenium.isVisible() --- How to use?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-8, visibility, runtime-error

I'm currently working with selenium to automate tests on my web application. I'm very confused as to how Selenium.isVisible() really works.

I am receiving the error (might I mention, quite sporadically):

> Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Error determining >if element is displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 83 milliseconds

The following is my code snippet:

```
        while (!selenium.isElementPresent("id=resultTable_0_0")){
        }
        selenium.isVisible("id=resultTable_0_0");
```

So what I'm doing is,

1.) Putting the program into a stalling loop until I find that the element that I will be taking action on, is **PRESENT**.

2.) Determining if the PRESENT element is actually visible or hidden, etc.

From my understanding of Selenium.isVisible() based on the selenium api referenced from the web, is that this will return either true or false. That is all that will happen.

Why am I receiving the error when running the script, and how can I remedy this occasional error?
It does not happen EVERY time I run it. I am running several scripts in series and constantly checking whether elements are visible so this is a huge issue for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did to solve this issue is put a delay before checking .isVisible()
I never get the error anymore.

Comment: It was probably due to the fact that I was checking for visibility RIGHT after checking presence of the element.